# In Angular, can I add css style together with double curly brackets?

Tags: css, angular, styles, expression

I am trying to create a style for my element using a variable name, which is a number, and adding % at the end. I am currently doing it inline like this:

```
<progress-bar
  style="{{batteryLifeLeft+'%'}}"
/>
```

What is wrong with it? Can you not add things together in this expression? I am getting the error: "Property value expected" and "at-rule or selector expected."

Comment: which style you want to apply i guess width? why didn't you give that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax would be `[ngStyle]="{'width.%': batteryLifeLeft}"`. https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

```html
<div style="width: {{ batteryLifeLeft }}%">
  {{ batteryLifeLeft }}% this wont work
</div>
<br />
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'width.%': batteryLifeLeft }">
  {{ batteryLifeLeft }}% this will work
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  batteryLifeLeft = 50;
  constructor() {}
}
```

Working example is on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-loop-object-keys-and-display-in-table-usin-jfoppw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)